# varchar to varbyte with out udf?

Tags: sql, teradata

I had a table definition with

```
SSN varbyte(100)
```

I just want to test my mload script ,
so I gave

```
CHAR2HEXINT(:SSN)    //SSN is defined as varchar in layout.
```

UTY0805 RDBMS failure, 3532: Conversion between BYTE data and
     other types is illegal.

Is there any way that i can convert varchar to varbyte with out using any UDF ?

```
NOTE:
```

I cant change my table definition , I just want to test my script .

Comment: Are you on TD 14? If so, you could look at making use of `TO_BYTE`...http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/ch04.074.108.html

Comment: I tried that , It still throws error .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just got access to the encrypt function and used that to load test data.

as suggested by dnoeth ,
 using TO_BYTES and FROM_BYTES to cast BYTE<->CHAR
seems to be working

Comment: The function visakh proposed is the wrong one, instead of TO_BYTE you can utilize TO_BYTES and FROM_BYTES to cast BYTE<->CHAR